# Mark all points in a triangle that have a certain property

Tags: plotting, graphics, computational-geometry

I want to mark all points inside of a triangle having the following property:

I can center a line segment of length $c$ on the point so that the line segment is entirely contained inside the triangle.

See the figure below that I created by hand.
The gray points have the property because I can center such a line segment there. Exemplary line segments are depicted in black.

Is there any way to produce a plot that visualizes this property?

Actually, I do not know how to start here.

[image: Visualization of the points (done by hand)]

Comment: So I understand, is your constraint equivalent to seeking all points inside the triangle whose distance from the edges is at least $c/2$? Or are there further restrictions on the orientation of the segment (eg horizontal)?

Comment: Not exactly. I added a figure that I created by hand (it's currently very small, I try to improve the size). All gray points (approximately) have this property because I can center such a line segment on them. The black line segments are two or three examples.

Comment: Maybe one can say that the points are at a distance of $\frac{c}{2}$ from at least two of the edges.

Comment: Should make more clear the definition of the gray domain.  Looks to me you take a line of length $L$.  Then define domain $D$ inside the triangle  such that you can center this line segment on any point  in $D$ and there is at least one orientation of the line that remains in the triangle.  Also add at least one point in the triangle examples as an example where centering the line results in part of it outside the triangle.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Write a function which computes given a *line segment $l$, a point $p$, and a length $d$*, the max and min angles which cause a length $d$ ray projected from $p$ to clip with $l$ (invalid angles).  Then evaluate that function symbolically for each segment of the triangle, and check if the max of the mins and the min of the maxes are a degenerate interval.  Pass that logical condition to `ImplicitRegion`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Edit

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0., 0.}, {10., 0.}, {5, 8}, {1, 6}} // Map@N // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
reg = Polygon[pts];
L = 8.0 // Rationalize;
conditions = 
  Exists[{x1, y1, x2, 
    y2}, {x1, y1} ∈ reg && {x2, y2} ∈ 
     reg && {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} . {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} >= L^2, 
   x == (x1 + x2)/2 && y == (y1 + y2)/2];
results = Resolve[conditions, Reals] // FullSimplify;
plot = RegionPlot[results, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, Prolog -> {EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], reg}];
domain = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
nearest = RegionNearest@domain;
pt0 = {x, y} /. FindInstance[results, {x, y}][[1]];
fig[pt_] := 
  Module[{instance, vector}, 
   instance = 
    FindInstance[{RegionWithin[reg, Line[{pt - {u, v}, pt + {u, v}}]],
       u^2 + v^2 >= (L/2)^2}, {u, v}];
   vector = If[instance =!= {}, instance[[1]], {u -> 1, v -> 0}];
   Show[plot, 
    Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt], 
       Arrow[{pt, pt - L/2 Normalize@{u, v}}], 
       Arrow[{pt, pt + L/2 Normalize@{u, v}}]} /. vector, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]]];
Manipulate[
 fig[pt], {{pt, pt0}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> {pt = nearest@#; &}}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

**Original**

- When `L=8`.

```
Clear[pts, reg, L, conditions, results];
pts = {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {5, 9.}} // Rationalize;
reg = Triangle[pts];
L = 8.0 // Rationalize;
conditions = 
  Exists[{x1, y1, x2, 
    y2}, {{x1, y1} ∈ reg, {x2, y2} ∈ 
     reg, {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} . {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} >= 
     L^2}, {x == (x1 + x2)/2, y == (y1 + y2)/2}];
results = Resolve[conditions, Reals] // FullSimplify;
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], reg}], 
 RegionPlot[results, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  MaxRecursion -> 4]]
```

[image]

- When `L=5`.

[image]

- We can test convex polygon.

```
Clear[pts, reg, L, conditions, results];
pts = {{0., 0.}, {10., 0.}, {5., 8.}, {1., 4.}} // Rationalize;
reg = Polygon[pts];
L = 8.0 // Rationalize;
conditions = 
  Exists[{x1, y1, x2, 
    y2}, {x1, y1} ∈ reg && {x2, y2} ∈ 
     reg && {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} . {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} >= L^2, 
   x == (x1 + x2)/2 && y == (y1 + y2)/2];
results = Resolve[conditions, Reals] // FullSimplify;
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], reg}], 
 RegionPlot[results, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]]
```

[image]

- Or random convex polygon.

```
SeedRandom[10];
reg = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 5}, DataRange -> {0, 10}];
reg = Polygon@Rationalize[MeshCoordinates[reg], 0]; 
L = 10.0 // Rationalize;
conditions = 
  Exists[{x1, y1, x2, 
    y2}, {x1, y1} ∈ reg && {x2, y2} ∈ 
     reg && {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} . {x2 - x1, y2 - y1} >= L^2, 
   x == (x1 + x2)/2 && y == (y1 + y2)/2];
results = Resolve[conditions, Reals] // FullSimplify;
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], reg}], 
 RegionPlot[results, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot about Mathematica and also about the regions I defined.

Answer (score 11):

If we phrase out the problem as "for each point `{x, y}` in the sought region there exists a line passing through it on which both points at the distance `l/2` from `{x, y}` are inside the triangle", the problem is basically already solved with use of `RegionMember`, `Exists` and the Pythagorean theorem.

Pretty similar to the @cvgmt's answer, but anyway:

```
With[
 {rt = RegionMember[RegularPolygon[3]],
  l = 29/20},
 Resolve[
   Exists[{u, v},
    u^2 + v^2 == (l/2)^2,
    rt[{x, y} + {u, v}] && rt[{x, y} - {u, v}]],
   Reals] //
  RegionPlot[{rt[{x, y}], #},
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1/2, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 200, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &]
```

[image]

This of course relies on the fact that triangles are convex. This solution also extends to polygons and other regions that are convex, but `Resolve`'ing the equations is certainly easiest for plain old triangles.

---

**EDIT**:

It can be also shown how the hole in the middle is formed by tracing midpoints of line segments whose both ends reside on the triangle boundary:

```
With[
  {poly = RegularPolygon[3],
   l = 29/20},
  With[
   {background =
     With[{rt = RegionMember[poly]},
      Resolve[
        Exists[{u, v},
         u^2 + v^2 == (l/2)^2,
         rt[{x, y} + {u, v}] && rt[{x, y} - {u, v}]],
        Reals] //
       RegionPlot[{rt[{x, y}], #},
         {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1/2, 1},
         PlotPoints -> 200, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &]},
   With[
    {boundary = RegionBoundary[poly]},
    Table[With[
      {o = RegionIntersection[boundary,
          Line[{{0, 0}, {Sin[a], -Cos[a]}}]][[1, 1]]},
      Show[
       {background,
        Graphics[{Line[{o, #}],
            Point[{o, Midpoint[{o, #}], #}]} & /@
          RegionIntersection[Circle[o, l], boundary][[1]]]}]],
     {a, 0., 2 Pi, Pi/60}]]]] // ListAnimate
```

[image]

Comment: Why should there be a hole in the middle of your feasible region? Shouldn't points in the middle of the triangle be included as well?

Comment: @MarcoB The same occurs also with @cvgmt's solution. If you insert `Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, -1/4}], Arrowheads[{-1, 1}/20], Arrow[{{-29/40, -1/4}, {29/40, -1/4}}]}` you can see that there is simply no space for the line segment midpoint to fit in the interior area...

Comment: (+1) Good idea of using the vector `{u,v}`  instead of two points,  very faster!

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I could only accept one answer.